# Paradigmatic way to layout QTableView vertically

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview, qtwidgets

I have a `QTableView` that shows a model with many columns.

The model contains something like `vector<my_item_with_lots_of_fields>`; for most applications the size of `vector` is below 5.

For aesthetic reasons, the model would look better flipped so that each entry would run from top to bottom.

One dirty solution is to change the model so that the row and column indexing is switched. Unfortunately this would break other widgets that access the model.

Is there some easy, paradigmatic way to achieve this effect without changing the underlying model? Perhaps to change the widget?

Comment: I think you meant 270 degrees, not 90, but I edited the question the way that is more human readable. The degrees may confuse some people.

Comment: I think question could be made clearer. Normally, what you want is described as a transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one approach would be to create a proxy model for this. You would then need to do two changes:

1) [data method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data)

```
QVariant MyProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex & index,
                            int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
{
    return myTableModel::data(QModelIndex(index.column(), index.row()), role);
}
```

2) [headerData method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#headerData)

```
QVariant MyProxyModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                                  int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
{
    return myTableModel::headerData(section,
           orientation == Qt::Horizontal ? Qt::Vertical : Qt::Horizontal, role);
}
```